# semaphores + pthreads, not working properly

Tags: c, pthreads, semaphore

I have this graph of process. In every thread new process begin. First is process 1, when it ends semaphores are posted and next possible process are 2 and 4. 

This graph explain more : [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AoPCY.png): http://i49.tinypic.com/34t5uo0.png .My script crashes in some times. Process 1,2, or 4 do not execute. Where is a problem ?

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <semaphore.h> 




sem_t semA,semB,semC,semD,semE;


void* process_2 (void* param)
{ 
  sem_wait(&semA);
  int pid2, status2; 
  pid2 = fork ();
  if ( pid2 < 0 ) {
   exit(1);
  }
 if ( pid2==0 ) { 

  printf("Process 2\n");
  }
 else {
  wait(&status2);
  sem_post(&semC);
 } 
 return NULL;
}

void* process_4(void* param)
{   
 sem_wait(&semB);
 int pid4, status4;
 pid4 = fork ();
 if ( pid4 < 0 ) {
  exit(1);
 }
 if ( pid4==0 ) { 

   printf("Process 4\n");


  exit(0);
 }
 else {
  wait(&status4);
  sem_post(&semD);                          
 }


 return NULL;
}


void* process_3(void* param)
{
 sem_wait(&semC);
 int pid3, status3;
 pid3 = fork();
  if (pid3 < 0) {
  exit(0);
 }
 if (pid3 == 0) {  

   printf("Process 3\n");
 }
 else{
  wait(&status3);
  sem_post(&semE);
 }

 return NULL;

}

void* process_5(void* param)
{
 sem_wait(&semD);
 sem_wait(&semE);
 int pid5, status5;
 pid5 = fork();
 if (pid5 < 0) {
   exit(0);
 }
 if (pid5 == 0) {  
  printf("Process 5\n");
 }
 else{
  wait(&status5);
  exit(0);
 }

 return NULL;

}



int main () {

  pthread_t thread_id[4];
  pthread_create(&thread_id[0], NULL,&process_2, NULL);
  pthread_create(&thread_id[1], NULL,&process_3, NULL);
  pthread_create(&thread_id[2], NULL,&process_4, NULL);
  pthread_create(&thread_id[3], NULL,&process_5, NULL);


  sem_init(&semA,0,0); 
  sem_init(&semB,0,0);
  sem_init(&semC,0,0);
  sem_init(&semD,0,0);
  sem_init(&semE,0,0);


  int pid, status;


  pid = fork ();
  if ( pid < 0 ) {
   exit(1);
   }
  if ( pid==0 ) {  
   printf("Process 1\n");    
   }
  else { 
   wait(&status);
   sem_post(&semA);
   sem_post(&semB);
   int i;
   for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    pthread_join(thread_id[i],NULL);   
   return 0;
   }
 exit(0);

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least one problem is you spawn the threads before initializing the semaphores:

```
pthread_t thread_id[4];
pthread_create(&thread_id[0], NULL,&process_2, NULL);
pthread_create(&thread_id[1], NULL,&process_3, NULL);
pthread_create(&thread_id[2], NULL,&process_4, NULL);
pthread_create(&thread_id[3], NULL,&process_5, NULL);


sem_init(&semA,0,0); 
sem_init(&semB,0,0);
sem_init(&semC,0,0);
sem_init(&semD,0,0);
sem_init(&semE,0,0);
```

This creates a race condition between the main thread initializing the semaphores and the child threads using them.  There is a really good chance of using uninitialized data here.

I recommend swapping the order in your main() function:

```
pthread_t thread_id[4];

sem_init(&semA,0,0); 
sem_init(&semB,0,0);
sem_init(&semC,0,0);
sem_init(&semD,0,0);
sem_init(&semE,0,0);

pthread_create(&thread_id[0], NULL,&process_2, NULL);
pthread_create(&thread_id[1], NULL,&process_3, NULL);
pthread_create(&thread_id[2], NULL,&process_4, NULL);
pthread_create(&thread_id[3], NULL,&process_5, NULL);
```

Comment: This only notes part of the problems that you have in your code. I listed them in a separate answer, because that would be much too long to list in a comment.

Answer (score 2):

Ben's answer shows you your main problem, but you have others. You are taking programming with threads, processes and semaphores much to easy.

- Semaphores are not to be programmed like this. All the semaphore
  functions give error return codes for a good reason. E.g `sem_wait`
  may encouter "spurious wakeups" if the process receives a signal. So
  you'd have to check the return and then `errno` to see what happened,
  there is no way around this when programming POSIX semaphores.
- Semaphores are only an optional feature in POSIX. It is probably
  easier to start with the POSIX features that were designed into it
  from the beginning, namely `pthread_mutex_t` and `pthread_cond_t`.
  What you obtain as a supplement is portability. There are still very 
  common architectures around that don't fully support semaphores.
- The way your are doing this is *not* the way to share semaphores
  between processes:

  > The entire virtual address  space  of  the  parent  is     replicated 
  >   in  the  child

  which means that the semaphore in the child is a copy, and the two
  processes will not be able to communicate through it. You'd have to
  use something like `shm_open` and `mmap` create process shared
  semaphores.
- Mixing `fork` and threads is usually not a trivial task and you
  should really think twice before doing that.

Comment: +1 for not mixing pthread_create() and fork().  I totally missed that when I focused on the initialization problem.  That being said, I do think its reasonable to use semaphores if they are on the questioner's target platform.  Also, you can pass `1` for the second argument of `sem_init()` to make them shareable across processes.

Comment: @BenKelly, as a side remark it is `0` to be shareable. But that is not the point, if you fork, they might be shareable, but they are two different objects after the fork. Both processes see them at the same address, but refer to different beasts.

Comment: Sorry, you are correct.  I read the first part of the docs, "If pshared is nonzero, then the semaphore is shared between processes," but missed this part:  "and should be located in a region of shared memory (see shm_open(3), mmap(2), and shmget(2))."  Sorry for my confusion!